# Constrain 3D plot size?

Tags: plotting

I have a `ContourPlot3D` that plots three planes:

```
planes = {-4 x + 5 y + 5 z == 10, -2 x - 3 y - 2 z == -5, -5 x + 5 y + 2 z == 7};

ContourPlot3D[planes, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
              AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Medium, 
              SphericalRegion -> True]
```

In my application, I would like to restrict the user from being able to scale the size of the plot or be able to move it by clicking the orange border around it without restricting their ability to rotate the plot.

Putting it in a `Row` with `Selectable -> False` restricts the ability to rotate. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, if my request isn't feasible, its not the end of the world.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Dynamic` to lock the image size:

```
planes = {-4 x + 5 y + 5 z == 
    10, -2 x - 3 y - 2 z == -5, -5 x + 5 y + 2 z == 7};

DynamicModule[{size = Medium}, 
 ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate@planes, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Mesh -> None, 
  ImageSize -> Dynamic[size, (size = Medium) &], 
  SphericalRegion -> True]]
```

You can still rotate, but when you try to resize, it just gets reset to `Medium` and nothing happens.